# What is the etymology of the term 'hunch'?

Tags: etymology

Oxford states the etymology as:

> late 15th century: of unknown origin. The original meaning was ‘push, shove’ (noun and verb), a sense retained now in Scots as a noun, and in US dialect as a verb. [The] noun derives probably from a US sense of the verb ‘nudge someone in order to draw attention to something’.

**Hunch** in Scots means 'push' as a noun. Did the Scots not use it as a verb? Why did the US use it as a verb?

In the example below, the meaning of 'hunched over' is 'bent over' according to the Guided Compositions book.

> The usual hectic traffic awaited me as I hunched over the steering wheel of the company car.

Comment: https://idiomorigins.org/origin/hunch

Comment: @user 66974, The link is useful to learn etymology of hunch better.   Did not check idioms origin earlier as i thought hunch is not an Idiom. thanks for the link. can post it as answer ? I will mark this as accepted answer after that

Comment: Idiomorigins doesn't cite any references or give any examples. How trustworthy is it?

Comment: By 'Scots' they seem to mean the Scottish dialect of English. I'm sure Scottish people use the English verb _to hunch_ in the sense _raise (one's shoulders) and bend the top of one's body forward._ (which is what your 'hunched over' means).

Comment: @Kate Bunting, In Scottish Dialect the hunch is used as verb. understand. But this line from oxford languages page is a bit confusing...... “ , a sense retained now in Scots as a noun, and in US dialect as a verb. Sense 1 of the noun derives probably from a US sense of the verb ‘nudge someone in order to draw attention to something’.”

Comment: @Stuart J, understand that giving proof for etymology for some words is really difficult. can understand and i am also not interested in references. Only thing is the sentence from oxford languages search is not clear on verb and noun parts

Comment: Oxford says that, in the Scots dialect, 'hunch' in its _original_ sense of 'push' is used as a noun. They think that the noun with the meaning _a feeling or guess based on intuition rather than fact_ probably comes from an American usage of the word meaning 'a nudge'.